# ¿Como auto-reproducir un video con HMTL5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

quiero que un video se reproduzca de manera automatica en mi web, por ahora tengo el siguiente código:

```
<video width="440px" loop="true" autoplay="autoplay" controls>
  <source src="src="http:tuvideo.com/mivideo.mp4"" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Espero puedan colaborar. No importa que debamos meter Javascript. Saludos.

Comment: No veo ningún problema en lo que has puesto, lo unico que se me ocurre es que en algun navegador no le haga gracia `autoplay="autoplay"`, asi que simplemente pon `autoplay`

Comment: Actualmente estoy en una Mac pero no reproduce y en las PC con Windows tampoco :'( Deja intento con puro autoplay.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el video ha de cargar entero antes de que empiece a reproducir, puede que tengas que esperar.

Comment: No funciona! :(

Comment: Según la nueva política en el navegador la [release 66](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/03/chrome-66-beta-css-typed-object-model.html): en adelante, ya no se reproducirá automáticamente ningún medio que produzca sonido. Este nuevo comportamiento ha generado fallos inesperados en miles de páginas y proyectos web, así como en juegos, [causando quejas ante estas políticas](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) por parte de los desarrolladores.

Comment: Si se puede amigo, recuerda que somos magos. La respuesta la deje yo mismo en la parte de abajo, saludos.

Comment: Si, a decir verdad en diciembre hice un proyecto donde lo solucione pero no sabia nada de esto tube que tomarlo en cuenta, ya que uno de los requisitos es que no tenga audio para reproducirlo automáticamente , Saludos

Comment: Hace unas semanas trabajando con un video en HTML5 me tocó buscar ayuda, pues se estaba reproduciendo solo después de cargar la página y no quería ese comportamiento. Por tanto, te puedo decir que Chrome no es tan estricto con esta regla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El formato correcto para hacer reproducir un video es el siguiente:

```
    <video loop="true" muted autoplay style="width:1000px;">
       <source src="http:tuvideo.com/mivideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </div>
```

Les debo confesar que solo funciona en Chrome si agregas la instrucción "**muted**".

Les comento que una buena forma de involucrar a los usuarios es usar la reproducción automática silenciada y así es como a mi me funciono. Espero les sirva de algo. Saludos.

Fuente oficial: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#mei

Answer (score 0):

Como se te comentó anteriormente por @Francisco Garrido, debes agregar la etiqueta `autoplay`, prueba removiendo el atributo si gustas del siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<video width="440px" loop="true" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://viajesacuba.mx/images/slider/SLIDER-CUBA.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Tal vez estás colocando el atributo en un lugar incorrecto, verifícalo.
Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Asi como lo pusiste no me dejaba amigo, gracias por el apoyo, agregue "muted" y funciono.

Comment: Enterado, aunque si ejecutas el ejemplo si se reproduce de manera automática en el snippet y allí si funciona... es buena la información que compartiste, la tomaré en cuenta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En Chrome `autoplay` funciona solo si utilizas también el atributo `muted`

```html
<video id="video" width="360" height="450" autoplay muted loop>
 <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/twitter_cat.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Agradezco tu aporte amigo, ya había comentado la respuesta en la parte de arriba, hemos salvado muchas vidas! Saludos.